# Андроид LinearLayout блоки налазят друг на друга

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.Имеются блоки.В зависимости от нажатой кнопки блоки появляются справа,лева,сверху и снизу.Необходимо снизу экрана встроить блок с рекламой.На картинки блок с данными зеленым цветом, а реклама черным.Перепробовал все но блок с рекламой то поверх данных, до за данными.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.myadbtest.myadbtest.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#2bff00"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Подскажите как правильно расположить блок с рекламой снизу экрана а остальные уже над ним?

Answer (score 3):

У верхнего `LinearLayout` уберите `alignParentBottom` и `paddingBottom`. 
Поместите нижний `LinearLayout` на самый верх разметки

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
< вот сюда нижний />
<а под ним второй />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Дайте чёрному `LinearLayout`  id - например, `banner`.
Зелёному добавьте

```
android:layout_above="@id/banner"
```